# Can I use matplotlib.units to switch between the units displayed on a graph?

Tags: matplotlib

I’m using matplotlib to render graphs in a desktop application and I’m a little confused about matplotlib’s support of units. I want to let the user change the units shown on the *x* axis of a graph: all calculations will be done in nanometers, but the graph can be shown in either nanometers or gigahertz. (Note that there’s an inverse, not linear, relationship between these two units.)

There are two obvious ways to do this: “manually” or using matplotlib. In the former case matplotlib wouldn’t know anything about units; when the user changed the units I’d just recalculate all of my data points, change the axes’ bounds and labels, and tell matplotlib to redraw. But I’m hopeful that matplotlib has built-in functionality to do the same thing.

There is some [light documentation about `matplotlib.units`](http://matplotlib.org/api/units_api.html), but as far as I can tell this is intended for plotting arrays of user-specified objects instead of arrays of, say, floats. My data actually is an array of floats, and since there are hundreds of thousands of data points per graph I can’t wrap each value in some custom model class. (Even [this simple example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/units/evans_test.html) wraps each data point in a model class, and the entire example is so generic I can’t tell how I’d adapt it for my needs.) In any case, the original data points always have the same units, so the values only ever need to be converted *to* another unit.

How can I tell matplotlib about my units and then just use `axes.set_xunit` or something to change between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find a satisfactory way to do this using matplotlib—I didn’t want the overhead of wrapping each data value in an object. I decided just to do the unit conversion myself before passing the data to matplotlib.

Answer (score 2):

**Try to use a function instead of a float for conversion**

The following example could serve as a start. Gigahertz `GHz` is `per nanosecond` and `nm^-1` is `per nano meter`, so this example would give `nm^-1` I guess.

I took the mpl mock-up and made three adaptations:

Support a callable function for conversion

```
def value( self, unit ):
    if callable(unit):          # To handle a callable function for conversion
        return unit(self._val)
    ...
```

Define function for conversion

```
one_by_x = lambda x: 1 / x if x != 0 else 0
....
```

Pass it

```
ax.plot( x, y, 'o', xunits=one_by_x )
....
ax.set_title("xunits = 1/x")
```

You define some functions and replot with the appropriate one. 
Or - for complication - even add another argument and have both: A constant scaling factor plus function.

The entire adapted example from http://matplotlib.org/examples/units/evans_test.html:

```
"""
A mockup "Foo" units class which supports
conversion and different tick formatting depending on the "unit".
Here the "unit" is just a scalar conversion factor, but this example shows mpl is
entirely agnostic to what kind of units client packages use
"""
from matplotlib.cbook import iterable
import matplotlib.units as units
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Foo:
    def __init__( self, val, unit=1.0 ):
        self.unit = unit
        self._val = val * unit

    def value( self, unit ):
        if callable(unit):
            return unit(self._val)
        if unit is None: unit = self.unit
        return self._val / unit

class FooConverter:

    @staticmethod
    def axisinfo(unit, axis):
        'return the Foo AxisInfo'
        if unit==1.0 or unit==2.0:
            return units.AxisInfo(
                majloc = ticker.IndexLocator( 8, 0 ),
                majfmt = ticker.FormatStrFormatter("VAL: %s"),
                label='foo',
                )

        else:
            return None

    @staticmethod
    def convert(obj, unit, axis):
        """
        convert obj using unit.  If obj is a sequence, return the
        converted sequence
        """
        if units.ConversionInterface.is_numlike(obj):
            return obj

        if iterable(obj):
            return [o.value(unit) for o in obj]
        else:
            return obj.value(unit)

    @staticmethod
    def default_units(x, axis):
        'return the default unit for x or None'
        if iterable(x):
            for thisx in x:
                return thisx.unit
        else:
            return x.unit

units.registry[Foo] = FooConverter()

# create some Foos
x = []
for val in range( 0, 50, 2 ):
    x.append( Foo( val, 1.0 ) )

# and some arbitrary y data
y = [i for i in range( len(x) ) ]

one_by_x = lambda x: 1 / x if x != 0 else 0
# plot specifying units
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle("Custom units")
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
ax.plot( x, y, 'o', xunits=one_by_x )
for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(30)
    label.set_ha('right')
ax.set_title("xunits = 1/x")


# plot without specifying units; will use the None branch for axisinfo
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax.plot( x, y ) # uses default units
ax.set_title('default units')
for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(30)
    label.set_ha('right')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Unless I’m mistaken this still requires each data point to be wrapped in a class (`Foo` in this code). I really don’t think that’s practical for my application, which will have hundreds of thousands of data points on each graph, and a new graph every couple of seconds. Is there a way to do this with “plain” floats?

Comment: @bdesham Oh, I didn't even pay attention to that. Anyway, I think you need to replot your data meaning you need to re-compute it. You could wrap the plot function into a customized function which takes a function as argument or just write to wrappers, one for the `nm`, one for the `GHz`. If you vectorize your conversion function, I'd say that should work. However, you did say exactly what data size you expect.  I'd think, if it is plot-able, then it'll be rescale-able.

Comment: @bdesham Maybe you'd just re-plot it with e. g. `ax.plot( x, 1./y)` or whatever it needs to be. If you have numpy arrays, its pretty fast, cause they are vectorized.. `a = np.arange(1, 1e7); %timeit 1. / a; 10 loops, best of 3: 53.8 ms per loop`